# I have Elan Touch Drivers presently installed on my laptop touchpad. Can I install Synaptics?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have Elan Touch Drivers. I was wondering if I could install Synaptics Touch Drivers, because  Elan has announced no plans on those extremely intuitive Windows 8 touchpad drivers that Synaptics will release in the near future.

Also, how do I determine how many touch points my touchpad supports? I know that it supports dual-touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, you should not expect drivers from one vendor to work for devices from another vendor.  This is like trying to use an AMD video driver on an Nvidia graphics card.  (The exception to this rule is, of course, the base drivers that come with Windows - for some devices, they may offer full functionality...but I'm guessing these don't, because you're asking this question.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the drivers available for your machine at your laptop's manufacturer's website. I'm just going through the same thing myself. Lenovo has Synaptics, Elan, and Alps available.

Comment: This appears to be a comment.  Instead of answering a question and simply saying you also have the same problem you should have used the comment system.

Comment: It's the answer. As noted, I found a Synaptics driver available at the Lenovo support site for my Lenovo computer, all properly labled and approved by Lenovo for what I have. Note that the question does not tell what the laptop is, so no one can add links and such. Questioner will need to follow the suggested procedure on their own.

Comment: Anwswer: "Check the drivers available for your machine at your laptop's manufacturer's website."

Comment: Are you saying you were able to use Synaptics or Alps drivers for an Elan touchpad?